# Should Search User be capitalised

Tags: language

I have a search bar and I don't know what should be capitalised and what not.

There would be two solutions:

Search User

Search user

Which one should I use?

Comment: Related: [Is it default that an English version is always Title Case, while other languages like Dutch don't use Title Case?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72790/is-it-default-that-an-english-version-is-always-title-case-while-other-language) and [Are there guidelines for when to use UPPERCASE, Capitalize Each Word, or Only the first letter?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75454/are-there-guidelines-for-when-to-use-uppercase-capitalize-each-word-or-only-th)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there guidelines for when to use UPPERCASE, Capitalize Each Word, or Only the first letter?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75454/are-there-guidelines-for-when-to-use-uppercase-capitalize-each-word-or-only-th)

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Search user" will be the best one. In some place, we have to compromise the look and feel to achieve good UX writing practice.

For example, In every video post, Facebook and youtube use like below:

Facebook 8 months before : 1.1K Views  34 Comments  3 Shares
Latest update            : 1.1k views  34 comments  3 shared

You can check your video feed on your Facebook page for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The battle between use Title-case vs Sentence-case is going on for ages, Apple prefer to use Title-case in their interface while Microsoft goes with Sentence-case.

```
https://blog.prototypr.io/sentence-case-or-title-case-5bd581f05d88
```

Though you should decide on emphasis and context. If text is full sentence like "Search for users" then sentence-case make sense, while if you want to emphasize on the individual words and make it easy to skim then go with Title-case.
In your case title-case would provide better user experience.

Comment: Sounds great. Thank you very much. I am not a native English speaker, so I never know if something is really wrong or if you can do it this way or that way.